# Python changing a value in a list changes them all unintentionally

Tags: python

I have a class:

```
class Tree(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 100
```

And I use it here:

```
tree_list += [Tree()] * random.randint(4, 12)
```

This makes the list contain multiple Tree() classes. The problem is that when I change 'health' in one of the items in tree_list:

```
tree_list[0].health -= 25
```

It changes the 'health' value in EVERY item in tree_list. Can someone please help me figure out why it changes the value for every item instead of the item I intend to change? Any help would be appreciated. :D

Comment: "*This makes the list contain multiple Tree() classes.*" No, it makes a list of multiple *objects*, not classes. Except it only creates a single object, then puts it in the list multiple times. All list elements refer to the same object.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, I didn't even realise it did that.

Comment: This is also covered [in the official Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-did-changing-list-y-also-change-list-x). Meanwhile, the best answer on SO is to a question that isn't _exactly_ the same as yours, so please let us know if it actually answers your question, or if we should add another link that isn't so list-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing this:

```
tree_list += [Tree()] * random.randint(4, 12)
```

To this:

```
for a in range(random.randint(4, 12)):
    tree_list.append(Tree())
```

Probably not the best way to do it, but it works now.

Comment: It's a fine way to do it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your solution. The most idiomatic way to do this is probably with a list comprehension: `tree_list = [Tree() for _ in random.randint(4, 12)]`. But your code has the same effect (in fact, it's just a more explicit way to write exactly the same operations), so if it's easier for you to understand/maintain, do it that way.